# User PowerShell to get IIS Recycling Time For Remote Server

Tags: powershell, iis, remote-server, recycle

I'm trying to create a script to audit the IIS recycling times on a number of remote servers.  The script I'm attempting is:

```
$scriptBlock = {
import-module webadministration
Get-itemproperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\WebPage -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection}
invoke-command -computername HOSTNAME -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

Unfortunately, this is returning absolutely nothing.  Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong, assuming you want to query the "DefaultAppPool," what you are doing will return empty if there is no value in the collection:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection
```

Set it with:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule -Value @{value = '03:00:00'}
```

And then try to get it, you will see the value.

Comment: No, I'm not going for the default.  I'm going for one called "webpage" and I can verify that it's set to 2AM...  But for some reason this returns no results when I try to pull it from a different location.  if I run

    import-module webadministration
    $iisrecycling = Get-itemproperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\WebPage -
    Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection
    $IISTime = $iisrecycling.value.hours

I get results locally, but not when trying to do it remotely.

Comment: The "DefaultAppPool" was just an example I was using to show you how to get it and set it. What do you mean by "remotely?" Through Posh remote session or on a different server?

Comment: I want to get it from a different server.  My goal is to audit about 50 servers with one query, but I can't get it to return the result from a single server, unless I'm signed directly into that server.

Comment: Ah, I see, let me check into that.